# how to group by month with summing or counting in R?

Tags: r

I am using the code below to group by month to sum or count. However, the SLARespond column seems like it sums for the whole data set, not for each month.

Any way that I can fix the problem?
also, instead of sum function, can I do count function with SLAIncident$IsSlaRespondByViolated == 1

Appreciate for helps!

```
SLAIncident <- SLAIncident %>%
mutate(month = format(SLAIncident$CreatedDateLocal, "%m"), year = format(SLAIncident$CreatedDateLocal, "%Y")) %>%
group_by(year, month) %>%
summarise(SLARespond = sum(SLAIncident$IsSlaRespondByViolated))
```

Comment: Don't use `SLAIncident$CreatedDateLocal`, instead use `CreatedDateLocal` and similar across all the variables.

Comment: And change `SLAIncident$IsSlaRespondByViolated)` to just `IsSlaRespondByViolated` as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you could provide a small bit of the dataset to illustrate your example that would be great.  I would first make sure that your months/years are characters or factors so that dplyr can grab them.  An ifelse function wrapped in a sum should also fit your criteria for the second part of the question.  I am using your code here to convert the dates into month and year but I recommend `lubridate`

```
SLAIncident <- SLAIncident %>%
  mutate(month = as.character(format(SLAIncident$CreatedDateLocal, "%m")), 
         year = as.character(format(SLAIncident$CreatedDateLocal, "%Y"))) %>%
  group_by(year, month) %>%
  summarise(SLARespond = sum(IsSlaRespondByViolated),
            sla_1 = sum(ifelse(isSlaRespondByViolated == 1, 1, 0)))
```

Also as hinted to in the comments, these column names are really long and could use some tidying